# Stripping styling on copy and paste with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, styles, copy-paste

I have a client who wants to be able to strip the styling from the text in their footer  which is currently white and pastes as white text. Is there a javascript function that would allow me to do this easily? I found this: http://bavotasan.com/2010/add-a-copyright-notice-to-copied-text/ and thought it might be at least a glimpse into how I would accomplish this task.

Comment: how have you applied what you have learnt from the above tutorial into what you are actually facing?

Comment: I'm looking at it now and it really seems like I should be able to use oncopy with the .style function but still haven't figured it out.

Comment: What are they pasting into?

Comment: We want site visitors to be able to copy and paste from the footer into any program without carrying over the white style that is on the text. Currently, the styles are copied as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually the "paste receiver" that controls what can be pasted, rather than controlling what can be copied.

You may be better off to have a "copy this" button that actually copies a hidden, unstyled, version of the copy into the clipboard instead.